# Speeding up a group by date query on a big table in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing

I've got a table with around 20 million rows. For arguments sake, lets say there are two columns in the table - an id and a timestamp. I'm trying to get a count of the number of items per day. Here's what I have at the moment.

```
  SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS day, COUNT(*)
    FROM actions
   WHERE DATE(timestamp) >= '20100101'
     AND DATE(timestamp) <  '20110101'
GROUP BY day;
```

Without any indices, this takes about a 30s to run on my machine. Here's the explain analyze output:

```
 GroupAggregate  (cost=675462.78..676813.42 rows=46532 width=8) (actual time=24467.404..32417.643 rows=346 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=675462.78..675680.34 rows=87021 width=8) (actual time=24466.730..29071.438 rows=17321121 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (date("timestamp"))
         Sort Method:  external merge  Disk: 372496kB
         ->  Seq Scan on actions  (cost=0.00..667133.11 rows=87021 width=8) (actual time=1.981..12368.186 rows=17321121 loops=1)
               Filter: ((date("timestamp") >= '2010-01-01'::date) AND (date("timestamp") < '2011-01-01'::date))
 Total runtime: 32447.762 ms
```

Since I'm seeing a sequential scan, I tried to index on the date aggregate

```
CREATE INDEX ON actions (DATE(timestamp));
```

Which cuts the speed by about 50%.

```
 HashAggregate  (cost=796710.64..796716.19 rows=370 width=8) (actual time=17038.503..17038.590 rows=346 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on actions  (cost=0.00..710202.27 rows=17301674 width=8) (actual time=1.745..12080.877 rows=17321121 loops=1)
         Filter: ((date("timestamp") >= '2010-01-01'::date) AND (date("timestamp") < '2011-01-01'::date))
 Total runtime: 17038.663 ms
```

I'm new to this whole query-optimization business, and I have no idea what to do next. Any clues how I could get this query running faster?

**--edit--**

It looks like I'm hitting the limits of indices. This is pretty much the only query that gets run on this table (though the values of the dates change). Is there a way to partition up the table? Or create a cache table with all the count values? Or any other options?

Comment: Are you telling us the whole story here?  It looks like you changed the memory settings between the first and the second plan.  Which would have been my advice. ;-)

Comment: No change in memory settings, though I have been doing a vacuum analyze between every schema change. Don't know if I'm supposed to do that, but it does seriously affect the results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Is there a way to partition up the table?*

Yes:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html

> *Or create a cache table with all the count values? Or any other options?*

Create a "cache" table certainly is possible. But this depends on how often you need that result and how accurate it needs to be.

```
CREATE TABLE action_report
AS
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS day, COUNT(*)
    FROM actions
   WHERE DATE(timestamp) >= '20100101'
     AND DATE(timestamp) <  '20110101'
GROUP BY day;
```

Then a `SELECT * FROM action_report` will give you what you want in a timely manner. You would then schedule a cron job to recreate that table on a regular basis.

This approach of course won't help if the time range changes with every query or if that query is only run once a day.

Comment: Oh nice. Creating a cache table will definitely solve the problem. Selects from that table are (obviously) super fast. Having day old data in there is fine, and having a 20 second update once a day is no problem either. Is there a way to update the table with the most recent week or so, as opposed to dropping and recreating each time?

Comment: You don't need to create each time. Once created simply do a `TRUNCATE action_report` followed by a `INSERT INTO action_report SELECT ....`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the cache suggestion.  Inspiring!

Comment: For @g33kz0r and anyone finding this question now, look into materialized views - they have the same effect but, as of postgres 9.4, they can be refreshed concurrently, so you never have to have a time where the table is locked / empty.

Answer (score 2):

In general most databases will ignore indexes if the expected number of rows returned is going to be high.  This is because for each index hit, it will need to then find the row as well, so it's faster to just do a full table scan.  This number is between 10,000 and 100,000.  You can experiment with this by shrinking the date range and seeing where postgres flips to using the index.  In this case, postgres is planning to scan 17,301,674 rows, so your table is pretty large.  If you make it really small and you still feel like postgres is making the wrong choice then try running an analyze on the table so that postgres gets its approximations right.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the range covers just about covers all the data available.

This could be a design issue. If you will be running this often, you are better off creating an additional column timestamp_date that contains only the date.  Then create an index on that column, and change the query accordingly.  The column should be maintained by insert+update triggers.

```
SELECT timestamp_date AS day, COUNT(*)
FROM actions
WHERE timestamp_date >= '20100101'
  AND timestamp_date <  '20110101'
GROUP BY day;
```

If I am wrong about the number of rows the date range will find (and it is only a small subset), then you can try an index on just the timestamp column itself, applying the WHERE clause to just the column (which given the range works just as well)

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS day, COUNT(*)
FROM actions
WHERE timestamp >= '20100101'
  AND timestamp <  '20110101'
GROUP BY day;
```

Comment: Yes, the filter is for a large subset of the data. Queries of a smaller subset are generally fast enough - it's only the big queries that are slow. I tried adding the timestamp_date column, and an index. Unfortunately neither option gives a significant speed up. Here's the output: http://pastie.org/1454799

Comment: Why would that make a difference?  An index on `date(timestamp)` with a query involving `date(timestamp)` will have the same effect as an index on `timestamp_date` with a query involving the `timestamp_date` column.

Comment: @Peter Eisentraut you must have cast the downvote. Regardless of what you think, check out the actual result from zaius's test. It did come out marginally faster. That is, if 10% is still marginal and not significant.

Comment: I don't know which test result you are referring to.

Comment: @Peter Eisentraut - link to pastie.org in zaius's first comment to my answer above your comment

Answer (score 1):

Try running `explain analyze verbose ...` to see if the aggregate is using a temp file. Perhaps increase `work_mem` to allow more to be done in memory?

Comment: Here's the output from verbose: http://pastie.org/1455439
Which doesn't look too different. (Note that I added more data in because I refreshed from the production db)

Comment: which version of postgresql are you using?

Comment: I'm running all these tests in my dev environment, which is postgres 9.0.1 on mac. Production (where the performance actually counts) runs on 8.3 on Ubuntu. I can upgrade production if needed though.

Answer (score 1):

Set `work_mem` to say 2GB and see if that changes the plan.  If it doesn't, you might be out of options.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want for such DSS type queries is a date table that describes days.  In database design lingo it's called a date dimension.  To populate such table you can use the code I posted in this article: http://www.mockbites.com/articles/tech/data_mart_temporal

Then in each row in your actions table put the appropriate date_key.

Your query then becomes:

```
SELECT
   d.full_date, COUNT(*)
FROM actions a 
JOIN date_dimension d 
    ON a.date_key = d.date_key
WHERE d.full_date = '2010/01/01'
GROUP BY d.full_date
```

Assuming indices on the keys and full_date, this will be super fast because it operates on INT4 keys!

Another benefit is that you can now slice and dice by any other date_dimension column(s).